# My Grand Central Dispatch usage: Am I using it correctly?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am fetching data from a server in JSON format. It's only about 150 records and I was not using GCD initially but every now and again when I hit the button in the app to view the table with data it would delay for about a couple of seconds before switching to the table view and displaying the data. So I implemented GCD and now when I hit the button it switches to the tableview immediately but then there is a few seconds delay in loading the data, which seems longer than the pre-GCD implementation. So I'm not sure if I am using GCD correctly, or if it's my server causing the delay (which I think is the culprit). Here is the implementation of GCD in a method called retrieveData which I call in viewDidLoad as [self retrieveData]:

```
- (void)retrieveData
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),^{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MY_URL/JSON/document.json"];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //Set up our exhibitors array
    exhibitorsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++) {
        //create exhibitors object
        NSString * blabel = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"BoothLabel"];
        NSString * bName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
        NSString * bURL = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"HyperLnkFldVal"];


        exhibitors * myExhibitors = [[exhibitors alloc] initWithBoothName: bName   andboothLabel: blabel andBoothURL: bURL];

        //Add our exhibitors object to our exhibitorsArray
        [exhibitorsArray addObject:myExhibitors];

        //Sort by name
        NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
        [exhibitorsArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    }

    [self.myTableView reloadData];

        });
    });

}
```

Comment: You want to avoid using self in your blocks as it can lead to retain cycles. Check out this blog post for an example of how to create a weak reference to self to use inside your blocks: http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=160

Comment: You should not use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` for accessing remote resources. At any rate, utilize `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode and implement the delegates. It gives also much more debugging as well as optimization opportunities. It becomes mandatory anyway when you implement more advances features, like cancellation of requests which is a required behavior for any app which behaves sane in various usage scenarios: means, it does not crash when the user switches views, is not hogging the CPU and does not consume memory for performing requests the user isn't interested anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically correct. Dispatch the data retrieval to the background queue, and then dispatch the model and UI update back to the main queue. Well done.

In terms of its being slower, I don't see anything there that would account for that. GCD introduces some overhead, but generally not observable. It may be a bit of a "watched kettle never boils" issue.

A couple of unrelated thoughts, though:

1. I might suggest moving the sort to outside of the `for` loop, but before the `reloadData`. You're sorting it 150 times. If doing an insertion sort, you could do it within the loop, but I don't think that's happening here. I'd move the sort to the end of the loop. I'm not sure if the performance gain will be observable, but there should be some modest improvement.
2. You might want to make sure `data` is not `nil` (e.g. no network, or some other network issue), because if it is, `JSONObjectWithData` will crash.
3. Your `json` object is an external variable. It should probably be a local variable of your `retrieveData` method. There's no need to make it an instance variable. It's cleaner to make it a local variable if appropriate.
4. You probably should adopt the naming convention whereby class names start with uppercase letters (e.g. `Exhibitor` instead of `exhibitors`).
5. Very minor point, but your `blabel` variable should probably be `bLabel`. Even better, I might rename these three variables `boothLabel`, `boothName`, and `boothUrlString`.
6. You're using instance variable for `exhibitorsArray`. I presume you're doing this elsewhere, too. You might want to consider using [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/DeclaredProperty.html) instead.
7. You might want to turn on the network activity indicator before dispatching your code to the background, and turning it back off when you perform `reloadData`.

   ```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
   ```
8. If you wanted to get really sophisticated, you might reconsider whether you want to use GCD's global queues (because if you refresh 10 times quickly, all ten will run, whereas you probably only want the last one to run). This is a more complicated topic, so I won't cover that here, but if you're interested, you might want to refer to the discussion of operation queues the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), in which you can create operations that are cancelable (and thus, when initiating a new operation, cancel the prior one(s)).

   You might also want to refer to the [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) WWDC 2012 video.

But this is all tangential to your original question: Yes, you have tackled this appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I implemented both. And now that I look at it the delay is about the same both with and without GCD. Just that with GCD at least I have a 'loading data' indicator after it switches to the tableview which shows to the user that there is something happening in the background. But even after switching to another server the 2 - 3 second delay still occurs intermittently, and the JSON file is only about 80kb.

Comment: @bachma0507 Yeah, with a response this small, the issue isn't the size of the response (which undoubtedly transmits fairly quickly once it starts), but network latency involved in any web requests (and perhaps some server latency, as well). There can be quite a bit of variability in this latency as well. That's why it's so critical to do it asynchronously, which you've done perfectly. Well done.